# Make repeating image stick to footer?

Tags: html, css

I originally created [this site](http://www.kimoswim.co.uk/index.html) in Adobe muse and then used adobe BC to add some of the functions. I am in the process of recreating the site because the code is so messy from Adobe Muse it is impossible to keep on top of.

I am struggling to get the wave effect which sits on the top of the footer.

Here is my code at present;

https://jsfiddle.net/Gar3H/215/

```
<div id="footerDecor"></div>
<div id="footerWrapper">

<div id="footer">

<p>MOTIVATE, INSPIRE & EDUCATE</p>

<div class="footerFloat">
<h4>Header 1</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<div class="footerFloat">
<h4>Header 2</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Line 1</li>
  <li>Line 2</li>
  <li>Line 3</li>
  <li>Line 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footerFloat">
<h4>Header 3</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Line 1</li>
  <li>Line 2</li>
  <li>Line 3</li>
  <li>Line 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footerFloat">
<h4>Header 4</h4>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div id="copyrightInfo">
<p>© 2014 Kim O Swim. All Rights Reserved.&nbsp;|&nbsp; Site and brand design by <a href="http://www.transitiongraphics.co.uk">Transition Graphics</a></p>
</div>

</div>

</div> <!-- end footerWrapper -->

    #footerDecor {
    background: url(/images/wave-footer.png) center repeat-x;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}

#footerWrapper {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    background-color: #333333;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.footerFloat {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
#footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
} 
.footerFloat {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
}
#copyrightInfo {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

P.s. I also want the footer to stick to the bottom of the browser, just thought this may be easily resolved at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Gar3H/216/

CSS Update:

```
#footerDecor {
    background: url(http://www.kimoswim.co.uk/images/wave-footer.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

The container that holds the background image needs to have a specified width and height or it won't show with the background image (since that technically takes up no space.  Give it a width of 100% and a heigh and it shows up repeating horizontally.